# How to resolve ERROR 010271: Raster does not have an attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, cost-path

From my code which builds least-cost paths between several polygons by using the functions "CostDistance" and "CostPath" of ArcGIS , I obtain this error message:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 010271: Raster Selected_patch_2 does not have an attribute table
ERROR 010067: Error in executing grid expression.
Failed to execute (CostPath).
```

This error appears when I execute this code line:

```
outCostPath = CostPath("Selected_patch_2", "outCostDist.tif", "outCostLink.tif", "EACH_ZONE","FID")
```

Here my piece of code:

```
rowsInPatches_2 = arcpy.SearchCursor("Select_transitions_from_patch_1")

for rowPatches_2 in rowsInPatches_2:

ID_patch_2 = rowPatches_2.getValue("ID_patch_2") 

expressionForSelectInPatches_2 = "ID_patch_2=%s" % (ID_patch_2)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Patches_2_day.shp", "Selected_patch_2", expressionForSelectInPatches_2)

    rowsSelectedPatch_2 = arcpy.SearchCursor("Selected_patch_2")

    shapeNameSelectedPatch_2 = arcpy.Describe("Selected_patch_2").shapeFieldName

    for rowSelectedPatch_2 in rowsSelectedPatch_2:

        featSelectedPatch_2 = rowSelectedPatch_2.getValue(shapeNameSelectedPatch_2)

        extentSelectedPatch_2 = featSelectedPatch_2.extent

        outCostDist = CostDistance("Selected_patch_1", "DayCost.tif", "", "outCostLink.tif")

        outCostDist.save("outCostDist.tif")

        outCostPath = CostPath("Selected_patch_2", "outCostDist.tif", "outCostLink.tif", "EACH_ZONE","FID")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving looks it can be avoided by adding the [Build Raster Attribute Table (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000m2000000) tool to your script prior to using the CostPath tool because it:

> Adds a raster attribute table to a raster dataset or updates an
>   existing one.

As an aside your code looks like it has been created by exporting a model to a Python script.  My recommendation is not to do that because, since 10.0, the code it creates is not guaranteed to run without error and can be quite hard to debug.

Rather than authoring a model, exporting the Python script and then debugging it, I think it is much easier to run each tool from its dialog and then [use the Results window to Copy As Python Snippet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002100000013000000) the syntax it used straight into a Python script.

Comment: Thanks very much PolyGeo. I added `arcpy.BuildRasterAttributeTable_management("outCostDist.tif", "Overwrite")` just before the CostPath tool but I obtain an error message `ERROR 000423: Only single band integer raster dataset is a valid input`. I don't understand why `outCostLink.tif` is a valid input and not `outCostDist.tif`. `outCostDist.tif`has not statistics. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: That sounds like a new question so would you be able to research/ask it separately, please?  For example, try searching on that new error code and message both here and also via your search engine of choice.  Debugging code is often a process of working through any errors thrown one at a time.